# foreach behaviour in function, in package, with custom iterator

Tags: r, foreach, iterator

I have created a custom iterator, inheriting from there `iter` class in the `iterators` package. The iterator and its methods are not exported from the package. Here is the iterator and a test function in a script that is reproducible and runnable, the iterator is called pairsRef:

```
library(Biostrings)
library(iterators)
library(foreach)    

setGeneric("maskSequences", function(object, seqnames, invert = TRUE, append = "union"){
  standardGeneric("maskSequences")
})


setMethod("maskSequences",
          signature("DNAMultipleAlignment", "character", "logical", "character"),
          function(object, seqnames, invert, append) {
            sequenceNames <- rownames(object)
            rowmask(object, append = append, invert = invert) <-
              which(sequenceNames %in% seqnames)
            return(object)
          })

pairsRef <- function(obj, ...){
  UseMethod('pairsRef')
}

pairsRef.DNAMultipleAlignment <- 
  function(obj, ref = NULL, checkFun = function(x, ...) TRUE){
    state <- new.env()
    state$i <- 0L
    state$obj <- obj
    if(is.null(ref)){
      state$ref <- rownames(obj)[1]
    } else {
      state$ref <- ref
    }
    state$nonRefs <- rownames(obj)
    state$nonRefs <- state$nonRefs[state$nonRefs != state$ref]
    it <- list(state=state, checkFun = checkFun)
    class(it) <- c("pairsRef", "abstractiter", "iter")
    return(it)
  }


nextElem.pairsRef <- function(obj, ...){
  repeat {
    obj$state$i <- obj$state$i + 1L
    if(obj$state$i > length(obj$state$nonRefs))
      stop('StopIteration', call.=FALSE)
    pair <- maskSequences(obj$state$obj,
                          c(obj$state$ref, obj$state$nonRefs[obj$state$i]),
                          invert = TRUE,
                          append = "replace"
    )
    if(obj$checkFun(pair)){
      return(pair)
    }
  }
}

Test2 <- function(dna, ref){
  pit <- pairsRef(dna, ref = ref, checkFun = function(x) TRUE)
  results <- foreach(x = pit, .combine = c, .multicombine = TRUE) %do% {x}
  return(results)
}


dna <-
  readDNAMultipleAlignment(filepath =
                             system.file("extdata",
                                         "msx2_mRNA.aln",
                                         package="Biostrings"),
                           format="clustal")

Test2(dna, rownames(dna)[1])
```

However, I want to use this iterator to do foreach loops in a package of mine.
If I put Test2 in a package (exported), and I have all the other functions in the package (unexported), and I have the package namespace import Biostrings, iterators, and foreach. It does not work. With a fresh R session, loading the package, and the running:

```
dna <-
  Biostrings::readDNAMultipleAlignment(filepath =
                             system.file("extdata",
                                         "msx2_mRNA.aln",
                                         package="Biostrings"),
                           format="clustal")

Test2(dna, rownames(dna)[1])
```

Results in an error: "Error in { : attempt to apply non-function"

Is this because the custom iterator is internal to the package? Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

[EDIT] - If I export the iterator and it's functions from the package. Then all works fine. But I don't necessarily want to export iterators of the package.

Thanks,
Ben.

Comment: Where is the reproducible example?

Comment: Apologies @Roland, I have made my code much more reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for it to work inside the package, the method nextElem must be imported from iterators, and then the additional method unique to the package, exported, such that it is visible to the functions in the foreach package namespace.